# Image processing - convert 33/35mm picture to 100+ mm

Tags: iphone, image, image-processing

iPhone's focal length ranges from 30-35 mm depending on the model. My question is, is it possible by image processing, using same focal length to capture a photo which is as if taken with 100mm or 125 mm?

I have searched all over and could not any answer. Also, if this is not possible please describe the technicalities of lens and software why this could not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another point of view: If you neglect distortion, the effect of focal length is effectively the magnification power of the lens, which is inversely proportional to field of view (FOV); see an example image in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length#In_photography.

So, in order to *simulate* a different focal length (again, supposing the lens distortion is  the same), you should do a "digital zoom" or, in practice, just crop the image. This will give you a "magnificated" image with a proportionally reduced FOV, like the third image in the picture from the link above (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Angleofview_70mm_f4.jpg) compared to the leftmost one (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Angleofview_28mm_f4.jpg). In this sense, it is actually easy to simulate a larger focal length.

Of course, the limitation here is that as you crop, you will reduce the resolution of the output image. In this sense, it is impossible to properly simulate a larger focal length.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is entirely impossible..

Please learn more about camera focal length [Wikipedia: focal length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length)
Focal length is basically a purely hardware component, Not even a proper component, it is just the measure of how strongly a lens converges or diverges light... If you want to look better,... Just add a convex/concave lens before the lens, since you know its focal length, you can calculate the light paths in a 100nm Focal length system and can add a suitable convex/concave length which simulates such.. But no. it is entirely impossible (as far as my knowledge concerns) to process an image in such way

Comment: This is not focal length of an optical system. It is 35mm SLR camera lens equivalent focal length. So, it can be easily simulated.

Comment: user502144 - can you explain more?